# How too speed up a UNION TABLE query on milion record mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

this is my query

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT simple_sku, picture_url, product_name, discounted_price, tracking_link, 'Lazada.co.id' AS table_identity
        FROM `list_lazada`
        UNION
        SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, sale_price, tracking_link, 'Simulation.com' AS table_identity
        FROM `list_simulation`
    ) AS big_table
    WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY big_table.discounted_price ASC
    LIMIT 12 ";
```

now develop php with phpmyadmin.

Every table has 4 coloumn only

How to make it faster?

Comment: What indices do you have set? I'd create an index for product_name as this is a) common to both tables and b) used in the where clause.

Comment: @jeff how to add index on the union table? help please

Comment: @drew can you write a query, so i can try it

Comment: A query to do what? I would need to see your data and schema for it all to see if a redesign is needed. I have barely ever used unions ever due to poor speed and a sign of a poor schema design by the data architects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the outer subquery:

```
SELECT simple_sku, picture_url, product_name, discounted_price, tracking_link,
       'Lazada.co.id' AS table_identity
FROM `list_lazada`
UNION
SELECT id_product, picture_url, product_name, sale_price, tracking_link,
       'Simulation.com' AS table_identity
FROM `list_simulation`
WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%'
ORDER BY discounted_price ASC
LIMIT 12
```

I think your `LIKE` condition will render an index on the `product_name` column not usable, resulting in a full table scan.  But maybe you can improve your search approach to take advantage of an index.

Comment: Old Query 
Showing rows 0 - 11 (12 total, Query took 116.0073 sec) [discounted_price: 4000 - 15000]

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 11 (12 total, Query took 18.1356 sec)

Comment: but the result diferent

Comment: `but the result diferent` ... how is the result different?

Comment: i'm just manualy search the result
and your query prety good accurate

my old query not showing a true collect result
thanks you bro

Comment: sorry bro the Like condition not working
i'm just knew it